# advice about sharepoint migration from 2007 to 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have to migrate default and custom metadata on forms library. 
What I need to migrate are:

```
70 columns
15 linked lists (master data)
750 records

and from tasks lists I have to migrate the following:
- 35 columns
- 15 content types
- 2000 records
```

I was told that I should write powershell scrip and that's what they are expecting from me. Now, can anyone help me how to extract this information via powershell and export to sharepoint 2010? I have never used powershell, but it does not seem to be difficult since it resembles c#.

any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking at extracting columns i would look a gary le-points stsadm extensions i think he has a few that will be able to help you.

for examplke i think gl-exportsitecolumns and gl-exportsitecontenttypes <- these may not be exact but they will be close

Worry about getting the columns and Content Types in place once you have this you could just use data sheet to copy the data across.

Powershell help with the columns
http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/export-and-importcreate-site-columns-in.html

Powershell for the content types 
http://secretsofsharepoint.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/08/24/adding-content-types-using-powershell.aspx
Hopefully this should give you most of what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a try. Keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks Truezplaya for your help. I have one more quetion for you. How can I get the data with powershell now?

Comment: When you say the data do you mean the contents of the list? Export the data to excel. Import the data from excel in to the sharepoint list. This should work for you. i'm pretty sure a guy called todd klidnt (sorry if i have spelt his name wrong) has written a nice blog article about this

Comment: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349-3bb6-4087-94f4-7f95ff4ca81f&ID=91 <-