# save sharepoint 2007 list data as xml with powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I am trying to migrate some sharepoint 2007 lists.
Can anyone tell me what is the best way to save the sharepoint list data to xml with powershell?
I would like to save the column names and the data they contain.

Please help with some examples.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Powershell was introduced for SP2010 the 2007 alternative was stsadmin but that didnt have any functionality to migrate lists built in. Your best bet is to do something like manually exporting them via STPs

Answer (score 0):

Use Stsadm Gary la point extentions to get your columns and CT's

Build your lists with this info.

Export your data to excel and copy in.

See this other thread

[advice about sharepoint migration from 2007 to 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456556/advice-about-sharepoint-migration-from-2007-to-2010/11466225#11466225)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the other powershell-way around, that is in powershell load the .NET sharepoint assemblies and use the sharepoint object model.

Here you find a link to get started to this practice:
http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/09/03/preparing-powershell-for-sharepoint-and-moss-2007/